# Why Server Error in production but not in development?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

so I am wondering about a Server Error that occurs only in production (when the app is identical between production and development).

So, Using Flask-Admin, I display a basic CRUD interface, with model views that mostly rely on the model's __repr__ method to provide a readable string in the list view. In production (new app, same data as dev), I get a server error when the __repr__ method inadvertently does something stupid. In development, the same stupid behavior is ignored or unnoticed.

For example:

MODEL:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    # ...

    def __repr__():
        return '{}'.format(' '.join([self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name]))   # EDITED: Checked repository and I did have the arguments correct -- just wrote this off the top of my head.
```

__repr__() in this case causes an error ONLY on the server (which is wsgi on apache) when a first name, middle name, or last name are NULL. It attempts to concatenate NULL and String with join and thus causes some variant of "expected string, got NULL" to be raised.

But, on the development server, I never see these errors (nor any warnings).

I have since changed this repr method to check for first name, middle name and last name before concatenating, but I am at a loss as to why the error occurs in production (wsgi app) but not in development (flask dev server or cherrypi server).

So, any ideas? What is different between the two situations?

Comment: Are you using different database backends? They probably treat empty or `null` strings differently.

Comment: the `.join()` function takes one argument, in your case you are giving 3

Comment: So, both backends are sqlite -- and I tested this using the same database file when I started to get suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it strangely by converting NULL to None.

For example I create a function that is called in all views and converts all NULL values to None type. That way both in Development and in Production it worked flawlessly.

I also used flask dev server in Development and wsgi and apache2 in Production...

Why it worked I can't tell you!

Comment: I never did figure out why, just going to assign this to "Flask Magic" and move on with my life, lmao.